# I'm trying to redirect the js file using router in react js and bootstrap but unable to redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-router, web-development-server

/* this is for my portfolio i want to redirect to main page after a short video*/

> //importing packages as required

```
        import './App.css';
        import React from 'react';
        import Vid from './assets/codingmonkeyvid.mp4'
        import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
        import Secondary from './Secondary'
```

> // creating function to which it can redirect

```
        function Redirect() {
          return(
            <>
              <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                  <>
                    <Route path = '/' element = {<Secondary />}></Route>
                  </>
                </Routes>
              </BrowserRouter>
            </>
          );
        }
```

> //setting interval to redirect

```
        setInterval(() => {
          Redirect()
        }, 5000);
```

> //maincode

```
        function App() {
          return(
            <div>
              <center>
                <video src={Vid} autoPlay muted id='myVid'></video>
              </center>
            </div> 
          )
        }
```

> //end of code

```
        export default App;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where is the `Redirect` component being rendered? Why is it being invoked in the `setInterval`? Nothing in your code makes much sense React-wise.

Answer (score 0):

The `Route` component does not redirect. You need to import and return the `Navigate` component.

Importing:

```js
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
```

The redirect function:

```js
function Redirect() {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
}
```

You also need to create a route for the path if you didn't (somewhere in the App component).

```js
function App() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Secondary />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Note: if you are using react-router-dom v5, you will need to use its `Redirect` component instead of `Navigate`.

Comment: can you be more specific I'm new to react where should i add it before BrowserRouter tag?

Comment: That's how the function should look. You don't need BrowserRouter here.

Comment: function Redirect() {
  return(
    <Navigate to='./Secondary'/>
  );
}
like this?

Comment: The `to` attribute is a path. You don't need to pass a component but define a route for it.

Comment: my other file named secondary which I'm trying to open lies in the same folder. So, do I have to specify as /Secondary or something else?

Comment: That's not a path to your component file. It's a custom URL path you specified in the route. I edited the answer with the route created.